# Are there ways to improve a nested for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
r, c = len(x), len(y)
D0 = zeros((r + 1, c + 1))
D0[0, 1:] = inf
D0[1:, 0] = inf
D1 = D0[1:, 1:] # view
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        D1[i, j] = dist(x[i], y[j])
# x,y is numpy array.
```

I just want to know that how to improve it.

Comment: Yes, there are. If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, read the help center over at [codereview.se] and consider asking a better question there.

Comment: Just to add on what jonrsharpe has said in their comment, one important improvement would be to update the question text to state in words what this code seeks to accomplish. The title should also be updated to capture what the code seeks to accomplish.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I flagged that it requires moderator's attention, replies "Since this question does not clearly state in the question text what it is trying to accomplish, it does not reach the quality bar for migration. " I guess we can learn not to ask people to migrate in this circumstance.

Comment: @DanielCheung note that I said *"consider asking a better question there"*, which is **not** the same as suggesting it be migrated in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(x, y) and then transform the obtained vector to a matrix of the same dimensions as D1.